# Using tarantula to test a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, tarantula

I'm using [Tarantula](http://github.com/relevance/tarantula) to test a Rails app I'm developing.  It works pretty well, but I'm getting some strange 404s.

After looking into it, Tarantula is following `DELETE` requests (`destroy` actions on controllers) throughout my app when it tests.  Since Tarantula gets the `index` action first (and seems to keep a list of unvisited URLs), it eventually tries to follow a link to a resource which it had deleted...  and gets a 404.  Tarantula is right that the URL doesn't exist anymore (because it deleted the resource itself).   However, it's flagging it as an error -- that's hardly the behavior I would expect.

I'm basically just using the Rails scaffolding and this problem is happening.  How do I prevent Tarantula doing this?  (Or, is there a better way of specifying the links?)

**Updates:**

- Still searching, but I found a relevant thread here:  http://github.com/relevance/tarantula/issues#issue/3
- Seems to be coming from relying on JS too much, in a way (see also http://thelucid.com/2010/03/15/rails-can-we-please-have-a-delete-action-by-default/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, this is expected to be fixed in a future update of Tarantula.  (See also:  http://github.com/relevance/tarantula/issues#issue/3.)  For now, I'm ignoring 404s that "look harmless."

**UPDATE**

I'm now doing "soft deletes" (just marking records as deleted), so this isn't a problem for me anymore.